# intents not working, only the launch request is

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

wrote an Alexa intent with one costume intent, and a lambda function in python. problem is the only thing that works is the LaunchRequests and every time I'm trying to trigger any intent I get "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" whether is the built-in intents or the costume one and I can't figure out why...

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if event['session']['new']:
        on_start()
    if event['request']['type'] == "intentRequest":
        return intent_scheme(event)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event)
    elif event['request']['type'] == "SessionEndedRequest":
        return on_end()


def on_start():
    print("Session Started.")
def on_launch(event):
    onlunch_MSG = "Hi, welcome to the Carb Calculator. Provide any 
ingredient and I will respond with the number of carbs for the given 
portion and its daily value"
    reprompt_MSG = "please provide an ingredient"
    card_TEXT = "Provide an ingredient."
    card_TITLE = "Provide an ingredient."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(onlunch_MSG, 
card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def intent_scheme(event):
    intent_name = event['request']['intent']['name']

    if intent_name == "GetCarbsIntent":
        return GetCarbs(event)
    elif intent_name in ["AMAZON.NoIntent", "AMAZON.StopIntent", 
"AMAZON.CancelIntent"]:
        return stop_the_skill(event)
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.HelpIntent":
        return assistance(event)
    elif intent_name == "AMAZON.FallbackIntent":
        return fallback_call(event)
    elif intent_name == "LaunchRequest":
        return on_launch(event)
def on_end():
    print("Session Ended.")


def GetCarbs (event):
    ingredient = event['request']['intent']['slots']['ingredient'] ['value']
    ingredient.replace("","%20")
    url = 'https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser?ingr=' + 
ingredient + '&app_id=6f9d25da&app_key=c5b5242ee6008a2c036a4d7bd60c9aee'
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.json()["parsed"] == []:
        carbs = "You have provided an invalid ingredient"
        reprompt_MSG = "please provide an ingredient"
        card_TEXT = "repeat your request"
        card_TITLE = "invalid ingredient"
        return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(carbs, card_TEXT, 
card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)
    key = response.json()["parsed"][0]["food"]["nutrients"]["CHOCDF"]
    DVpercent = int ((key/300)*100)
    Carbs = "the number of carbs in" + ingredient + "is" +  key + "which 
is" + str(DVpercent) + "% of the recommended daily value"
    reprompt_MSG = "please provide an ingredient"
    card_TEXT = "processing " + ingredient
    card_TITLE = "processing " + ingredient
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(Carbs, card_TEXT, 
card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, True)

def stop_the_skill(event):
    stop_MSG = "Thank you. Bye!"
    reprompt_MSG = ""
    card_TEXT = "Bye."
    card_TITLE = "Bye Bye."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(stop_MSG, card_TEXT, 
card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, True)

def assistance(event):
    assistance_MSG = "you need to provide an ingredient in order to receive 
it's carbs value"
    reprompt_MSG = "please provide an ingredient"
    card_TEXT = "You've asked for help."
    card_TITLE = "Help"
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(assistance_MSG, 
card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)

def fallback_call(event):
    fallback_MSG = "I can't help you with that, try rephrasing the question 
or ask for help by saying HELP."
    reprompt_MSG = "please provide an ingredient"
    card_TEXT = "You've asked a wrong question."
    card_TITLE = "Wrong question."
    return output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(fallback_MSG, 
card_TEXT, card_TITLE, reprompt_MSG, False)


def plain_text_builder(text_body):
    text_dict = {}
    text_dict['type'] = 'PlainText'
    text_dict['text'] = text_body
    return text_dict


def reprompt_builder(repr_text):
    reprompt_dict = {}
    reprompt_dict['outputSpeech'] = plain_text_builder(repr_text)
    return reprompt_dict


def card_builder(c_text, c_title):
    card_dict = {}
    card_dict['type'] = "Simple"
    card_dict['title'] = c_title
    card_dict['content'] = c_text
    return card_dict


def response_field_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, 
card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value):
    speech_dict = {}
    speech_dict['outputSpeech'] = plain_text_builder(outputSpeach_text)
    speech_dict['card'] = card_builder(card_text, card_title)
    speech_dict['reprompt'] = reprompt_builder(reprompt_text)
    speech_dict['shouldEndSession'] = value
    return speech_dict


def output_json_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, 
card_text, card_title, reprompt_text, value):
    response_dict = {}
    response_dict['version'] = '1.0'
    response_dict['response'] = 
response_field_builder_with_reprompt_and_card(outputSpeach_text, card_text, 
card_title,

reprompt_text, value)
    return response_dict
```

Comment: Did you check the log of your Lambda function? They're available through AWS console > CloudWatch

Comment: incidentally, https://github.com/kennu/cwtail is a handy utility for monitoring these CW logs.